# How to install drivers for Mini PCIE WiFi or Bluetooth modules?

Tags: intel-galileo, windowsondevices, iot

I got the Intel Galileo Board with Windows Firmware on it, i have Mini PCIE Wifi and Bluetooth cards, how to install drivers for them on Intel Galileo with Windows On Devices Software.

Answer (score 1):

I think the actual release of Windows for Galileo is not compatible with wifi.

I have an Intel Centrino Wireless N 135 PCI-E wireless card, which is compatible with the official Yocto linux for galileo. I can connect to wifi networks using Yocto.

But the latest Windows image doesn't have drivers for my wifi card, I tried to install the drivers with pnputil and dpinst commands but Windows says both commands doesn't exists.

Also I revised the list of Windows services and "Wifi AutoConfig" isn't on the list, then I tried to set wlan settings using netsh but netsh don't have wlan settings.

So because I wasn't able to install drivers and there are not wireless services and settings I think wifi is not supported in the latest Windows image for Galileo.